# ¿Qué hace `git restore` y en qué se diferencia de `git reset` para descartar archivos de la zona de preparación?

Tags: git

Desde que uso git, siempre que he querido descartar un archivo de la zona de preparación lo he hecho usando `git reset HEAD -- <ruta/del/archivo>`, puesto que así se sugería en la ayuda de la terminal al hacer `git status`.

Hoy me he llevado una sorpresa cuando he visto que en la ayuda ya no se sugiere el anterior comando, sino `git restore -- <ruta/del/archivo>`.

**¿A qué se debe este cambio? ¿Es un *breaking change*? ¿Cómo se usará a partir de ahora?**

---

Por cierto, el comando `git reset HEAD -- <ruta/al/archivo>` sigue funcionando.

Comment: Cuidado, `git restore` restablece el archivo a su contenido anterior, perdiendo los cambios que realizaras. `git reset`, en su lugar, lo quita de la zona de preparación del próximo `commit`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Acabo de probarlo en mi terminal y no veo que ese sea el comportamiento.

Comment: Este es el enlace a la documentación: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_reset_restore_and_revert advirtiendo que ambos solapan funcionalidad: *`git reset` can also be used to restore the index, overlapping with `git restore`.* Creo que en el comentario anterior me confundí con `git revert`. Puedes crear tú mismo una respuesta con esta información.

Comment: Parece que es un comando aún en estado experimental, introducido en agosto de 2019. Yo seguiría usando reset. Mas info [en esta respuesta de SO (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003889/1264820)

Comment: @abulafia Ya he leído esa respuesta, además de la documentación que referenciaba Oscar. Mi intención es que se genere una respuesta temprana para personas a las que les pueda confundir un cambio repentino así.

Comment: @DavidDPG anímate a escribirla tú mismo :)

Comment: @fedorqui Lo haría encantado, pero no tengo tiempo. Por eso no la he autorrespondido al momento de preguntar, a ver si alguien lo hace por mí :)... hasta la he pasado por el chat.

Comment: No hay prisa, seguro que en algún momento tienes el tiempo... sumando momentos de aquí y allí. Si crees que va a ser útil para mucha gente puedes marcarla wiki y así más gente se podría animar a mejorarla.